# How do I use localstorage.getItem or setItem to send a post request in my react application?

Tags: reactjs, django

I am using jwt in authentication backend. According to a tutorial, I was able to successfully send a get request in react frontend using the following code.

```
export const load_user = () => async (dispatch) => {
if (localStorage.getItem("access")) {
 const config = {
   headers: {
     "Content-Type": "application/json",
     Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem("access")}`,
     Accept: "application/json",
   },
 };

try {
  const res = await axios.get(
    `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/auth/users/me/`,
    config
  );

  dispatch({
    type: USER_LOADED_SUCCESS,
    payload: res.data,
  });
  } catch (err) {
  dispatch({
    type: USER_LOADED_FAIL,
   });
 }
} else {
  dispatch({
   type: USER_LOADED_FAIL,
  });
 }
};
```

However, I am unable to send post request, I have tried coming up with my own code but still no success.
Here is my code:

```
export const client_information_create =
 (age, phone_number, country, city, alergy, gender) => async (dispatch) => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('access')) {
  const config = {
   headers: {
     "Content-Type": "application/json",
     "Authorization": `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('access')}`,
     "Accept": 'application/json'
   },
 };

 const body = JSON.stringify({
   age,
   phone_number,
   country,
   city,
   alergy,
   gender,
 });

 try {
   const res = await axios.post(
     `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/list/InformationView/`,
     body,
     config
   );
   if (res.data != null){
   dispatch({
     type: INFORMATION_SUCCESS,
     payload: res.data,
   });
 } else {
     dispatch({
       type: INFORMATION_FAIL,
     });
  }
 } catch (err) {
   dispatch({
     type: INFORMATION_FAIL,
   });
 }
```

}
};

Thanks for the help. The data is sent from the frontend but am getting a 403 Forbidden error. How do I avoid this error?

```
class ClientInformationView(APIView):

def get_object(self, pk):
    try: 
        return ClientInformation.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except ClientInformation.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
    client_information = self.get_object(pk)
    serializer = ClientInformationSerializer(client_information)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self, request, format=None):
    try:            
        serializer = ClientInformationSerializer(data= request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    except TypeError:
        return Response({
            'error':'Something went wrong when creating data'
        }, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

Comment: In what way does the request fail?  Are you getting an error on the browser's debugging console?  In the debugging tools, on the network tab, is the AJAX request made?  Does it contain the data you expect?  What is the server's response?

Comment: It is not recommended to use localstorage for storing tokens. I would recommend using dj-rest-auth that works good for django-react application. Below are the reference links to implement
1. https://medium.com/geekculture/jwt-authentication-in-django-part-1-implementing-the-backend-b7c58ab9431b
2. https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth/issues/97     -  for existing issue with the package.

Comment: Am getting a 403 forbidden error,

Comment: What error do you see

Comment: Am getting a 403 forbidden error,

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
const body = JSON.stringify({
   age,
   phone_number,
   country,
   city,
   alergy,
   gender,
 });
```

to

```
const body = {
   age,
   phone_number,
   country,
   city,
   alergy,
   gender,
 };
```

Comment: Okay thanks doing that

Comment: Hey, thanks for this solution, Everything seems okay, no errors. The data is not saved in the database. I am adding the class based view in the question. I am still not sure where the problem is.

Comment: Now am getting this error, TypeError: The `fields` option must be a list or tuple or "__all__". Got str.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got a solution to this question.
I modified the post request in views to this:

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = ClientInformationSerializer(data=request.data,)            
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data,    status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```